# Application Hosting

Tags: c#, hosting

There are some applications on my computer (Win XP Home) that are native WIN32 applications that I would like to host from an application built in .NET that could offer password protection before running sed application.

Is there a nice solution to my problem?

(over 2 years of C#.NET experience)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by host? Is the application an activex component?

You could do it if the application was a COM application. Just create a .net win form, create a wrapper around the application and call it from the winform. The winform could take care of your password authentication.

All said and done, I dont think what you are doing is a good idea. Might lead to crashes and cause debugging nightmares.

Cheers